# CUDA warp scheduling: another warp from the current block or a warp from another block?

Tags: cuda, scheduling

When a running warp on a SM is stalled, another warp must be scheduled on the SM to exchange the stalled one to cover latency. But is the substitute from the same block as the stalled warp or it must belong to another block, or both cases are OK?

Comment: Either case is OK.  The decision will be based on which warps are in the "ready-to-run" queue of the SM.  Latency can be hidden by having multiple warps either from the same block or multiple blocks ready to go.  The number of blocks that can be scheduled on a particular SM may be limited by factors such as shared memory usage, register usage, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I am not confused any more.

Comment: I know there is an optimization for lowering latency, that is using some smaller thread-blocks. Why does this method work or it only works under certain circumstances or it is just a fallacy?

Comment: Please see my comment to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585549/increasing-the-number-of-threads-per-block-decreasing-performance) for a (hypothetical) example which could illustrate why a smaller threadblock structure could help to hide latency better.  I'm not sure what you mean by "lowering latency".  I would say such a thing only works under certain circumstances.  Your mileage may vary, as there are a lot of contributing factors to think about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topic is an open research in GPU architecture community. People have evaluated several warp scheduling policies at [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hyesoon/gputhread.pdf). Look at the following recent papers for pros and cons of different scheduling policies:

- Some people suggest to use two-level warp scheduling for energy
  efficiency: [Energy-efficient Mechanisms for Managing Thread Context
  in Throughput Processors](http://dl.acm.org/authorize?445183)
- Some people suggest to use two-level warp scheduling for improving
  latency hiding: [Improving GPU Performance via Large Warps and
  Two-Level Warp Scheduling](http://www.istc-cc.cmu.edu/publications/papers/2011/improving-GPU.pdf)
- Some other people suggest to schedule the warp in the order reducing
  contention on L1 cache of SM:  [Cache-Conscious Wavefront Scheduling](http://www.ece.ubc.ca/~aamodt/papers/tgrogers.micro2012.pdf)
- And finally, [here is a patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120079241) from NVIDIA researchers proposing
  an scheduler for improving latency hiding and energy efficiency.

In answer to your question, both policies are OK and can be employed in any architecture. But the real underling has not been disclosed to public yet.

Comment: Thank you for these useful materials!